# Use Active Choices Reactive Parameter Plugin with Maven Metadata Plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-metadata

I used Active Choices Reactive Parameter for a selection menu which includes "Snapshots" and "Releases". And also used maven metadata plugin for list maven artifacts. There are two artifact types which are "Snapshots" and "Releases".

[image: activech]

Now, my requirement is when I selected "Snapshots" from drop-down menu of Active Choices should only active and display "SELECT_SNAPSHOTS_VERSION" section. "SELECT_RELEASES_VERSION" must be hide and inactive. Can we use Active Choices Parameter Plugin with Maven Metadata Plugin to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want to achieve is possible as all parameters are rendered at once when you start a build.

Comment: can't i write a groovy script? previously I wrote a groovy for "SERVER_SELECTION".                                                                                         
    `if (SELECT_ENVIRONMENT.equals("QA"))`
`{`
 `return["x"]`
`}`

`else if (SELECT_ENVIRONMENT.equals("Dev"))`
`{`
 `return["192.168.94.139"]`
`}`

`else if (SELECT_ENVIRONMENT.equals("Prod"))`
`{`
 `return["192.168.94.140"]`
`}`

`else if (SELECT_ENVIRONMENT.equals("Stress"))`
`{`
 `return["x"]`
`}`

Comment: Groovy script is for returning parameter values though not for the parameters themselves. Your requirement is to hide/ not show a parameter correct ?

Comment: Yes when I select "Snapshots" from dropdown only should display "SELECT_SNAPSHOT_VERSION" section.

Comment: Not possible to do that

Comment: Can't we use other plugin instead of maven metadata ?